# SQL multiple tables to allow null values

Tags: sql, null

I am new at SQL writing and have been trying to make this multiple table SQL work where I get null values from the WF tables. Basically not all transactions from GL tables got through Workflow, however I would like to see all transactions rows. The below works if I replace all left join with Where, but it will cut the transactions rows where it doesnt find a WF row.

```
SELECT GL20000.USWHPSTD,
   GL20000.LASTUSER,
   GL20000.SERIES,
   GL20000.ORPSTDDT,
   GL20000.TRXDATE,
   GL20000.ORGNTSRC,
   GL20000.JRNENTRY,
   GL20000.DEBITAMT,
   GL20000.CRDTAMNT,
   GL00105.ACTNUMST,
   GL00100.ACTDESCR,
   GL20000.REFRENCE,
   GL20000.DSCRIPTN,
   GL20000.ORMSTRID,
   GL20000.ORMSTRNM,
   GL20000.ORGNTSRC,
   SY30500.BCHTOTAL,
   SY30500.Workflow_Status,
   SY30500.USERID,
   WF30100.Workflow_Action,
   WFI10002.Workflow_Originator,
   WF30100.Workflow_History_User,
   WF30100.Workflow_Step_Name
FROM CORP.dbo.GL00100 GL00100,
 CORP.dbo.GL00105 GL00105,
 CORP.dbo.GL20000 GL20000,
 CORP.dbo.SY30500 SY30500,
 CORP.dbo.WF30100 WF30100,
 CORP.dbo.WFI10002 WFI10002
     left join GL20000.ORGNTSRC on SY30500.BACHNUMB
     left join GL00100.ACTNUMBR_1 on GL00105.ACTNUMBR_1
     left join GL00100.ACTNUMBR_2 on GL00105.ACTNUMBR_2
     left join GL00100.ACTNUMBR_3 on GL00105.ACTNUMBR_3
     left join WF30100.WorkflowInstanceID on WFI10002.WorkflowInstanceID
     left join GL20000.TRXSORCE on SY30500.TRXSORCE
     left join GL20000.ACTINDX on GL00105.ACTINDX
     left join ((right(rtrim(WFI10002.wfbusobjkey), 8) on convert(nvarchar(MAX),SY30500.TIME1,8))
     left join (left(WFI10002.dex_row_ts, 11) on left(SY30500.MODIFDT,11))
         left join (GL20000.ACTINDX on GL00105.ACTINDX) where (GL20000.TRXDATE Between {ts '2023-02-01 00:00:00'} And {ts '2023-03-31 00:00:00'})
AND (GL00100.ACTNUMBR_1='001'))
```

Comment: Hi - please start by formatting your SQL as code and make it readable. Also, can you provide sample data for the tables, as editable text, and the result you want to achieve based on that data

Comment: This "multiple table" syntax has been **obsolete** for **30 YEARS** (!) now. You should always write out the full `JOIN` for each table.

Comment: (1) You are mixing old and standard `JOIN` syntax in one statement which is not advisable and could create problems. (2) When you do `LEFT JOIN` your `WHERE` statements on *RIGHT* table should take into account `NULL` explicitly, Since in SQL `NULL` is not equal to ***anything***,  including another `NULL`.